# Using a new xrandr mode freezes the display

Tags: x11, xrandr

I am having an issue trying to adjust the resolution of my screen. I am running the following commands:

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00" 118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP-1 1600x900_60.00
xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1600x900_60.00
```

The first two commands are running fine, but on that last command, my display freezes, forcing me to hold down the power button to restart my machine. All three commands were running fine until I ran an update on my machine.

I was using this post as a guide for these commands: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Are there any suggestions about how I can fix this?

Here is some information about my system and the tiling window manager I am using:

```
[me]/me$ uname -a
Linux me 4.13.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 21 20:33:16 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[me]/me$ xmonad --version
xmonad 0.13
```

---

**Additional details:**

The mode on the first line was obtained by running `cvt 1600 900 60`, giving the following output:

```
[me]/me$ cvt 1600 900 60
Modeline  "1600x900_60.00" 118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

And here is the output of `xrandr` after the first two commands (note the new `1600x900_60.00` entry that I have added):

```
[me]/me$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   2560x1440     60.00*+
   1920x1440     60.00
   1856x1392     60.01
   1792x1344     60.01
   1600x1200     60.00
   1400x1050     59.98
   1280x1024     60.02
   1280x960      60.00
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   700x525       59.98
   640x512       60.02
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   512x384       60.00
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   320x240       60.05
   1600x900_60.00  59.95
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And here is some info on my drivers:

```
[me]/me$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 99)
```

Comment: i'm having the same problem with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 under VMware Cloud Director. `lspci` shows `VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this error by installing the `xf86-video-intel` and `libva-intel-driver` via pacman. Here are the related docs for those packages: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/community/xf86-video-intel and https://01.org/linuxmedia/vaapi

I also found this resource helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics

And I think this bug might also be related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1623936#p1623936

Also, after installing those packages, I discovered that there was a `1600x900` mode present in my `xrandr` by default, and I no longer needed to create a new mode for that resolution. So I've been using that, which also sidestepped the bug.