# xrandr with vmware freezes ubuntu display

Tags: drivers, display, vmware, xrandr, vga

When using `xrandr` to add and set a new display resolution, the display freezes on the new resolution. There is another [question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395400/using-a-new-xrandr-mode-freezes-the-display) that is nearly identical accept that they are referring to intel drivers instead of vmware.

1. `xrandr` -> "Virtual1"
2. `cvt 1920 1080 30` -> Modeline "1920x1080_30.00" 79.75 1920 1976 2168 2416 1080 1083 1088 1102 -hsync +vsync
3. `sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_30.00" 79.75 1920 1976 2168 2416 1080 1083 1088 1102 -hsync +vsync`
4. `sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 "1920x1080_30.00"`
5. In the display settings I select the new resolution "1920x1080...", click apply, and the display freezes.

running `lspci | grep VGA` result in `00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMWARE SVGA II Adapter`.  Based on the other thread with the intel drivers, I'm assuming I need to install VMWare vga drivers.  I have installed `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop` but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: I managed to add and change the resolution to **904x600@30**, and **1440x600@30** without the screen freezing.  **1920x600@30** freezes.

Comment: Windows VMs on the same system are limited to 1280x800 so I'm starting to think that this may be a limitation of the hypervisor.